# How to make ruby gems available to all users?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I installed a Ruby gem running this command from root:

```
gem install pushmeup
```

The gem works well when executing scripts from root. When I try to execute a script from non-root user, I see this error about such gem not found:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- pushmeup (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from pushAPNS.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Don't install gems as root user.

Comment: I'm already using rvm. How to switch to global gemset? After that, I can simply reinstall my gem with another gem install pishmeup or I need to uninstall it first? I'm on CentOS.

Comment: You can use root to uninstall the gem, then as non-root reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

> RVM gives you compartmentalized independent ruby setups. This means
>   that ruby, gems and irb are all separate and self-contained - from the
>   system, and from each other.

https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics

============

1. Never use `sudo` with rvm.
2. Type `rvm gemset list`
3. Type `rvm gemset use global`
4. Type `gem install some_gem`

The gems in the global gemset will be available in all other gemsets.  If you want to create a gemset for a specific project, then do:

1. `rvm gemset create proj1_gems`
2. `rvm gemset list`
3. `rvm gemset use proj1_gems`

To delete a gemset:

1. `rvm gemset delete proj1_gems`
2. `rvm gemset list`

Each version of ruby has its own gemsets.  You can switch to a specific ruby version and one of the gemsets for that version with one command like this:

```
rvm use 2.0.0@proj1_gems
```

But generally, I do:

1. `rvm use 2.0.0`
2. `rvm gemset list`
3. `rvm gemset use some_gemset_name_in_the_list`